# New Email Logo is NOT being shown in the Email?

Tags: shopping-cart

Even after replacing the default **Email/Print Logo** **(/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images )**, with Custom logo, the site is still sending email with Default Magento Logo.

Also set permission 644 for original Email Logo, just make sure.

Did clear cache.  Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto admin panel

> system > configuration > general > design > Transnational email

You can upload your logo there.
[image]